# Traducir plugin de wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugin, wordpress-plugin

tengo un pequeño problema, estoy tratando de traducir un plugin utilizando

wpml
locotranslate
polylang

Trate de moficar los archivos .po .mo, pero nada, no consigo que el plugin cambie de idioma, segun el desarrollador es de facil traduccion

```
/**
 * Creating widget front-end - This is where the action happens.
 * @param array $args
 * @param array $instance
 */
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

    $title  = ( isset( $instance['title'] ) && ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ) ? $instance['title'] : __( 'Monthly Mortgage Payments', 'mc' );
    $title  = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $title );

    $mc_total_amount_label      = ( isset( $instance['mc_total_amount_label'] ) && ! empty( $instance['mc_total_amount_label'] ) )          ? $instance['mc_total_amount_label']    : __( 'Total Amount', 'mc' );
    $mc_down_payment_label      = ( isset( $instance['mc_down_payment_label'] ) && ! empty( $instance['mc_down_payment_label'] ) )          ? $instance['mc_down_payment_label']    : __( 'Down Payment', 'mc' );
    $mc_interest_rate_label     = ( isset( $instance['mc_interest_rate_label'] ) && ! empty( $instance['mc_interest_rate_label'] ) )        ? $instance['mc_interest_rate_label']   : __( 'Interest Rate', 'mc' );
    $mc_mortgage_period_label   = ( isset( $instance['mc_mortgage_period_label'] ) && ! empty( $instance['mc_mortgage_period_label'] ) )    ? $instance['mc_mortgage_period_label'] : __( 'Mortgage Period', 'mc' );

    // before and after widget arguments are defined by themes
    echo $args['before_widget'];

    if ( ! empty( $title ) ) {
        echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
    }
    ?>
    <div class="mc-wrapper clearfx">
        <form id="mc-form" action="#mc-form">
            <p>
                <label for="mc-total-amount"><?php echo esc_html( $mc_total_amount_label ); ?></label>
                <input type="number" name="mc_total_amount_label" id="mc-total-amount" min="1" class="required" placeholder="<?php echo mc_get_option( 'mc_currency_sign', 'mc_settings', '$' ); ?>" value="<?php echo apply_filters( 'mc_total_amount', null ); ?>"/>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="mc-down-payment"><?php echo esc_html( $mc_down_payment_label ); ?></label>
                <input type="number" name="mc_down_payment_label" id="mc-down-payment" min="1" class="required" placeholder="<?php echo mc_get_option( 'mc_currency_sign', 'mc_settings', '$' ); ?>">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="mc-interest-rate"><?php echo esc_html( $mc_interest_rate_label ); ?></label>
                <input type="number" name="mc_interest_rate_label" id="mc-interest-rate" min="1" class="required" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e( '%', 'mc' ); ?>">
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="mc-mortgage-period"><?php echo esc_html( $mc_mortgage_period_label ); ?></label>
                <input type="number" name="mc_mortgage_period_label" id="mc-mortgage-period" class="required" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e( 'Years', 'mc' ); ?>">
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" id="mc-submit" value="<?php esc_html_e( 'Calculate Mortgage', 'mc' ); ?>">
            </p>
        </form>

        <!-- This div is holding output values-->
        <div id="mc-output" class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>

    <?php echo $args['after_widget'];
}
```

Seria de mucha ayuda que alguien me ayude :)

la respuesta con la solucion se gana un cafe/cerveza

Comment: reemplazar los `echo ...`  con `echo __(...) ` ?

Comment: en todo el codigo o solo las label?

Comment: en lo que quieras traducir : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/

Comment: Cual es el nombre del plugin y trato de traducirlo

Comment: saludos estimado te brindo link del plugin, por mas que lo intento no logro volverlo traducible con polylang ni wpml 

https://wordpress.org/plugins/mortgage-calculator/

Answer (score 0):

Hasta donde yo sé, el único plugin de los mencionados que necesitarías es LocoTranslate.

Al instalarlo vas a su menú y pinchas en "Plugins" 
Después seleccionas el plugin que quieres traducir y te sale la opción en la vista general de crear un nuevo idioma (supuestamente el español...)

Una vez creado el nuevo idioma, lo pinchas en el listado inferior de idiomas del plugin.
Y en las cadenas de texto que te salen buscas las cadenas de texto a traducir.

Tendrás por una parte el "Texto de origen" y abajo el "Texto de traducción" (que tienes que escribir tú).

Cada vez que traduzcas una cadena tienes que ir arriba y darle a guardar y ya te lo guarda en el fichero de traducción que has creado.

En esta mini explicación seguro que falta algún detalle, pero el procedimiento general es ese.
-Te lo estoy explicando de memoria-